# Power query pivot column error on sorted data works when not sorted

Tags: excel, powerquery

When i do a pivot column on unsorted data, it is working fine, but, when I do on a sorted data (same data), I receive the following error.

It would be really helpful to know how to get a work around.  The data is complete and no gaps are there for error.

[image]

My code is:

```
 #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"start_date", type date}, {"Surface Date", type date}}),
 #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Surface Date", Order.Ascending}}),
 #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Surface Date", type text}}, "en-US"),
List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Surface
Date", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Surface Date"]), "Surface Date",
"Answer Count", List.Sum)
```

I am using office 2013 Home and office with query 2.27.4163.242

If i remove the sorted rows step it is working good without error.

Below is full code for the query:

```
**let
    /* Get parameters for filtering*/
        Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Acitivity"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Surface Date", type date}, {"user_type", type text}, {"user_id", Int64.Type}, {"Subject", type text}, {"Total Surfaces", Int64.Type}, {"Answer Count", Int64.Type}, {"Surf", Int64.Type}, {"PrimaryBoard", type logical}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type",{"user_id"},EAsList,{"user_id"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Surface Date", "user_type", "user_id", "NewColumn", "Subject", "Total Surfaces", "Answer Count", "Surf", "PrimaryBoard"}),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "NewColumn", {"start_date", "Name", "Email", "RevokeDate"}, {"start_date", "Name", "Email", "RevokeDate"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{"Subject", "Total Surfaces", "Surf", "PrimaryBoard"}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Columns",NewEAsForAppending}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Appended Query",{"Subject"}),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Removed Columns1",0,null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Answer Count"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"start_date", type date}, {"Surface Date", type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Surface Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Surface Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Surface Date", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Surface Date"]), "Surface Date", "Answer Count", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"**
```

Replicating the file with dummy data is tough hence cannot upload the file.

Comment: No idea why this happens, but you could use Table.ReorderColumns after pivoting instead to sort your columns.

Comment: @ImkeF thank you for the suggestion - but the columns are dates and they are of dynamic ranges - so manual ordering is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new excel file and followed the same steps as above and it worked. Probably some bug only.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create the sort-order-argument for the pivoted columns like this:

```
NewOrder= Text.Split (Text.Combine ({"user_type", "user_id", "NewColumn", "Subject", "Total Surfaces", "Answer Count", "Surf", "PrimaryBoard"}, "-") &"-"& Text.Combine(List.Transform(#"Sorted Rows"[Surface Date], each Text.From(_)), "-"), "-")
```

You might need to adjust the field names above to those acutually remaining in your pivot. This step takes in the sorted column, transforms it to text before splitting it up into single words. They are then combined with the remaining field names in the pivot before rearranged into a list format (that you need to pass into the Table.ReorderColumns command)

You'd then reference your step "Pivoted Column" to step #"Changed Type1" instead:

```
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1", {{"Surface Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1", {{"Surface Date", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Surface Date"]), "Surface Date", "Answer Count", List.Sum)
```

And perform the sorting as the last step:

```
= Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column", NewOrder)
```

Comment: I will test this in office and let you know.  Thank you.

Comment: my dates are dynamic so giving the dates to combine is manual process - cannot implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill the table to Excel, do you get any rows with errors? For performance reasons Power Query will only perform the calculation for a limited number of rows in the Query Editor preview. The sort is probably moving the problematic closer to the top of the table, which could explain why you only see the error in that case.

Comment: there are no blank, error rows.  I checked it by removing pivot and looking into the data before pivot.

Comment: It is probably a bug then, as you stated here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dee5172a-44e4-4100-a1ca-0827f949d304/power-query-pivot-column-error-on-sorted-data-works-when-not-sorted?forum=powerquery